# Use DialogFragment's appearing theme for regular Fragment

Tags: android

I like Dialog Fragment's appearing theme: a dialog pop-up, outside is faded, if you click outside of the dialog disappears. I would like to use this style on regular Fragment but I don't know how. There must be a style somewhere in Android library but I don't know how to find it. Please help me out.

Edit 1: DialogFragment is behaving weirdly for me. Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="8">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/small_icon"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon_title">

    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon_title"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/save"
        android:contentDescription="@string/save"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<View style="@style/divider" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3">

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

There are some more items on the second and third Relative Layout but even when I cut it out I have had the same problem. I expect the Dialog to be divided by `LinearLayout` `android:weightSum=8`, such that the first `RelativeLayout` take up `1/8` of the Dialog. However, the first `RelativeLayout stretched out to the entire Dialog instead. Please point me some clues.

Answer (score 0):

There is a style but its *internal*.

Look at the Code at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/app/Dialog.java#Dialog.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context%2Cint%29

i would recommend to use a DialogFragment when you need a DialogStyle.

Comment: Thanks, I am having problem using `DialogFragment`, that's why I tried to switch to regular `Fragment`. I have edited my problem in the original post, please give me some comments.